# How can I use wildcards with ls to find files that are missing in a numeric sequence?

Tags: ls, wildcards

I'm trying to list missing files in a sequence in the terminal. While many answers existed here, they are not generic enough that I managed to adapt it to my situation. So if you can make a generic enough answer that will work for more people, please do it.

I'm doing `ls {369..422}.avi >/dev/null` to list missing files but I can't use * to match anything that ends with .avi. How can I do this?

The numbers are not in the end of the file but in the middle. So I should need something like `*numbers*.avi`

Comment: Do you want to match anything that ends in `.avi`, or anything that contains at least one number *and* ends in `avi`?

Comment: You probably would be better off using find with -regex

Comment: Anything that ends with ´.avi´ and has numbers in sequence on it

Comment: @RamanSailopal `find` will only find existing things. Freedo want's to check what's missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ls *{369..422}*.avi >/dev/null
```

This will first generate patterns like

```
*369*.avi
*370*.avi
*371*.avi
*372*.avi
*373*.avi
*374*.avi
```

through the brace expansion, and then `ls` will be executed with these patterns, which will give you an error message for each pattern that can't be expanded to a name in the current directory.

Alternatively, if you have no files that contain `*` in their name:

```
for name in *{369..422}*.avi; do
    case "$name" in 
        '*'*) printf '"%s" not matched\n' "$name" ;;
    esac
done
```

This relies on the fact that the pattern remains unexpanded if it did not match a name in the current directory. This gives you a way of possibly doing something useful for the missing files, without resorting to parsing the error messages of `ls`.

Comment: I think the final element is to redirect stdout, so that the *missing* files are reported to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. This works! However I'm more confuse than before since seems no files are missing other than the expected ones! Well, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Freedo Well, it's better to not have files expected to be missing than to miss files expected to be existing...

Comment: Can't you just escape the * using a \ , this should prevent the problems with names containing it

Answer (score 3):

If you want `*numbers*.avi`, you can do:

```
ls *[0-9]*.avi
```

The `[0-9]` specifies a character class consisting of all characters between `0` and `9` in your locale. That should be all numbers. So you want to match 0 or more characters (`*`), then a number `[0-9]` and then 0 or more characters again (`*`).

If you need to have more than one number in sequence, use:

```
ls *[0-9][0-9]*.avi
```

Finally, if you have files in numerical order and just want to find the missing ones, you could also write a little loop:

```
for avi in {369..422}.avi; do [ -e "$avi" ] || echo "$avi missing"; done
```

Comment: If I do your ls it will list all of files even after adding >/dev/null.

Comment: @Freedo yes, of course. You asked for `*numbers*avi` which will list everything. If you want to find only missing files, you need to give a better explanation in your question. You show file names that consist entirely of numbers (`{369..422}.avi`) but the say "*The numbers are not in the end of the file but in the middle. So I should need something like *numbers*.avi*" So I gave you what you asked for. Note that the loop in the end prints out the missing ones only. I find the loop more useful since you can trivially modify it to do something about each of the missing files.

Answer (score 3):

To list which of the `*{369..422}*.avi` patterns don't match any file, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
for p (\*{369..422}\*.avi) () {(($#)) || echo $p} $~p(N[1])
```

Or more verbosely:

```
for p (\*{369..422}\*.avi) () {
  if (($#)); then
    echo "$# file(s) matching $p"
  else
    echo >&2 No file matching $p
  fi
} $~p(N)
```

For files following a fixed pattern like: `foo-123-bar.avi`, you can also do:

```
expected=(foo-{369..422}-bar.avi)
actual=($^expected(N))
missing=(${expected:|actual})
print -l $missing
```

Some of the `zsh`-specific features in there:

- `x{1..20}y` brace expansion expanding to `x1y`, `x2y`.... Copied by a few other shells since.
- `for var (values) cmd`: short form of `for` loop
- `() compound-command args`: [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) like in many other languages.
- `$~p`: treat the content of `$p` as a glob (other shells do that by default, and even word splitting!)
- `(N[1])`: glob qualifier for globs to expand to no argument when they don't match any file. `[1]` select the first matching file only as we only one to tell whether there has been any match.
- `$^array`: brace-like expansion for the elements on an array
- `${array1:|array2}`: array subtraction
- `print -l`: print in lines

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:
`ls *{369..422}*.avi`

Comment: I think the final element is to redirect stdout, so that the *missing* files are reported to the terminal.

Comment: a good catch with one minor update: we'd better redirect just the error messages to /dev/null rather than whole output ;). i.e. 
ls *{369..422}*.avi 2>/dev/null

Comment: my interpretation was that the OP wanted to find the missing files and wasn't interested in the matching files

Comment: Yeah this list all files and not the missing ones

Comment: You are absolutely right. I misread the author's question.